# Can you alter an existing page using JavaScript and Firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox

I use a website to complete some work but I want to add some features to the site using JavaScript. I created the code using scratchpad in Firefox I just need a way to add this to the page everytime is loads. Can this be done with extensions in Firefox. What other options are available to do this?  The owner of the site will not add the extra features I require.

Comment: ive never done this natively but the Greasemonkey firefox extension is probably what you need

Comment: Try http://TamperMonkey.net

Answer (score 1):

To modify the content of web pages do you need use **Content Scripts**

An example:

```
// main.js

var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("content-script.js")
});
// content-script.js

document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts